# WinDiff-like utility?

Tags: windows, software-rec

My boss is looking for a comprehensive solution something like [WinDiff](http://www.grigsoft.com/download-windiff.htm), but a little different. Mainly he wants to be able to take the state of a machine (including registry and *all* files) on two different occasions and see the differences.

Are there any solutions out there? Preference to free, of course, but we're not opposed to commercial products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/11829/how-to-make-compare-filesystem-registry-snapshots-in-windows) has a post asking the the same question.

[TrackWinInstall](http://www.withopf.com/tools/trackwinstall/) looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try "beyond compare" program or the compare plugin for Notepad ++

Comment: Unfortunately those are only file system tools - we need registry as well